# Generation of Electrostatic induction

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical, electronics, inductive-charging

I need to generate a 500 volt electrostatic charge. How can I do this? I don't have a Van de Graaff generator. What are some practical suggestions?
Basically I want to do experiment in which I need to induce charges on a plate ie one side positive and another side negative, so what are some practical suggestions for me.
One of the approach is to place a metal plate inside a high voltage capacitor, how practical is this approach?

Comment: umm please be careful, especially if fooling around with HV caps. And ask the EE stack if you can. This one is more mechanical and "other" engineering.

Comment: There are [*voltage multiplier*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=voltage+multiplier) circuits which utilise **diodes, capacitors and a periodic low voltage waveform** to create large voltages.